# swimlane/ngx-graph Links are not displayed when data is updated via API calls

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-graph

Diagram is displayed when data set statically. But when tried to integrate with API, links are failing to display.

I have verified data is successfully fetched and nodes and links successfully set to valid data.

Nodes are displayed and link labels are shown but links are not displayed.

Links:

- Github issue raised: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/issues/266
- stackblitz link: https://angular-bge4wk.stackblitz.io/flow (static data)
- https://angular-bge4wk.stackblitz.io/flow1 (integrated API)

[image]

Comment: I went through your demo but couldn't find response for the API call. Its always empty.

Comment: @Arcteezy I need to update code to take response from json file, as I have created tunnel using ngRok for backend, which expires after some time.